# Expected primary expression in byte casting

Tags: solidity, remix, delegatecall, bytes, selfdestruct

I have a contract (Implementation.sol) which delegatecalls the other contract (Attacker.sol) to selfdestruct. When I try to compile the Implementation.sol on Remix, I receive `Expected primary expression` error for the line `require(success && dat != byte(0x0), "call failed");`. Not sure what to do.

```
contract Implementation {

  function delegateTheCall (address target, string calldata action, address to) public returns (bytes memory) {

    (bool success,bytes memory dat) = target.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature(action, to));
    require(success && dat != byte(0x0), "call failed"); 
    return dat;
  }
```

Comment: You probably want `dat.length != 0` instead of `dat != byte(0x0)`. But why having this condition? It's common for a function to return nothing and still succeed.

Comment: @0xSanson This is a better way to check the value. You're right. Thank you a lot. I'm just trying some experimental contracts to understand the concepts better. I definitely will not use these in prod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tricky to compare `string`s and `bytes` in Solidity. These two types are treated exactly the same in Solidity, only that `string` gets decoded in UTF-8 when returning it outside of the smart contract.

To compare these types, use `keccak256`:

```js
require(success && keccak256(dat) != keccak256(""), "call failed");
```

The empty string ("") is treated as an empty `bytes` array, which is what you need.

Try it doing something like this to check the result and you'll see what I mean. Comparing the `keccak256` hash of an an empty bytes array with the `keccak256` hash of an empty string (which is the same as an empty bytes array):

```js
bytes memory dat;
require(keccak256(dat) != keccak256(""));
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy Then. I definitely missed the point that you reminded me. It worked.